# move Items from a table to another sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have this code that moves data from one sheet to another sheet for records keeping purposes but I need the ID# to fill the along with the rest of the items for example

[image]

Currently the code output it like this

[image]

and this is where the source data will be

[image]

```
    Sub Button4_Click()
'Create and set variables for the Call Tracking & Call Log worksheets
Dim Form As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet

Set Form = Sheet1
Set DB = Sheet2


'Create and set variables for each cell in the call tracking sheet
Dim IDNum As Range, Item As Range, QTY As Range

Set IDNum = Form.Range("C9:D9")
Set Item = Form.Range("C11")
Set QTY = Form.Range("C13")


'Create a variable for the paste cell in the Call Log worksheet
Dim DestCell As Range

If DB.Range("A2") = "" Then 'If A2 is empty
    Set DestCell = DB.Range("A2") '...then destination cell is A2
Else
    Set DestCell = DB.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) '...otherwise the next empty row
End If

'If no "Number called has been entered, exit macro
If IDNum = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter an ID#"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Copy and paste data from the Call Tracking worksheet to the Call Log worksheet
IDNum.Copy DestCell
Item.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 1)
Country.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 2)
QTY.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 3)

Call Macro1
'Clear the contents in the Call Tracking worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set DestCell = DB.Range("A2")` `Set DestCell = DB.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` you're only ever setting it to 1 cell.

Comment: I am unsure how to set it so that IDNum copies with how ever many items there are

Comment: I prefer loops because that's how I think but arrays are faster for machines.

Comment: do you mean a loop just for IDNum ? and keep the rest the way it is or just a loop for everything ?

Comment: You loop all rows and it will transfer data row by row. Loops is a fundamental programming tool you will use over and over again. Look into it and live long and prosper ^_^

Comment: I am unsure as to how to implement that to here, the data is being bragged from another sheet that have the data in different cells as you can see in the code and transferring it to another sheet for records keeping,

Comment: If `IDNum` is C9:D9 and you copy it to (eg) A2, then it will paste to A2:B2 and then B2 will get overwritten by your copy/paste of `Item`.  Where is "Country" coming from?

Comment: Currently everything is transferring as it should the only issue I am having is making IDNum copy itself downwards with how ever many items are in column B:D

Comment: oh that table was just an example i see what you mean 

currently it looks somthing like this 
ID       Item    qty
123     apple  20
           grapes 23
           oranges 60

I need to do this instead 
ID       Item    qty
123     apple  20
123     grapes 23
 123    oranges 60

Comment: You can edit your question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73790741/edit) to add information  - the content in your comment isn't really legible.  A screenshot of the range you're copying from would also help - the code you posted only copies one row...

Comment: I do apologize for that, I have updated the post and the code to reflect the country source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (check the ranges are correct):

```vb
Sub Button4_Click()
    
    Dim Form As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, DestCell As Range, IDNum
    
    Set Form = Sheet1
    Set DB = Sheet2
    
    IDNum = Trim(Form.Range("C9").Value) 'useful to Trim user inputs...
    If Len(IDNum) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must enter an ID#"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'next empty cell in ColA
    Set DestCell = DB.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Set rw = Form.Range("B20:D20") 'first row of items
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0   'while source row has content
        DestCell.Value = IDNum            'write the id
        DestCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, rw.Cells.Count).Value = rw.Value 'transfer values
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1)             'next source row
        Set DestCell = DestCell.Offset(1) 'next paste
    Loop
    
    Call Macro1 'Clear the contents in the Call Tracking worksheet
    
End Sub
```

Note you can change the sheet codenames for `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to `Form` and `DB` respectively, then you can skip the worksheet declarations.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed!! thanks! how did you learn this? I am learning as I go by practicing but i have like the bare minimum lol

Comment: "I am learning as I go" - that's how it works    If you want a good grounding and you can spend the time then reading a good book on Excel VBA would be a good investment.  Something like https://www.amazon.com/Excel-2019-Power-Programming-VBA/dp/1119514924/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3EM79V4FC4UWT&keywords=power+programming+with+vba&qid=1663702198&sprefix=power+programming+%2Caps%2C165&sr=8-1 would give you a great start.

Comment: I will definitely check it out thanks once again!

Comment: Hey Tim, I do have another question, would you happen to know how to turn sheet 1 into a PDF and create an email with that PDF attached to the email?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+email+worksheet+as+pdf